# Regarding validating SMO XML in Mediation Flow in IBM WESB

Tags: websphere-esb

I want to validate the SMO XML flowing in Websphere Enterprise Service Bus(WESB) mediation module.
Is it possible to do it inside the Custom Mediation or I have to create a Java class for that?
And how can I do that? I'm clueless on how to approach this.
Also, if you can suggest any useful links to read more on this, I would appreciate that. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Custom mediation is a java class behind scene. 
In ESB, you can do schema validation of messages by setting the validation checkbox on xslt transformation primitive or you can use code in a custom mediation:

```
BOInstanceValidator validator = (BOInstanceValidator) new 
ServiceManager().locateService("com/ibm/websphere/bo/BOInstanceValidator");
boolean valid = validator.validate(dataObject, diagnosticList);
```

[Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/esbsoa/wesbv7r5m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wbpmcore.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2Fapidocs%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fbo%2FBOInstanceValidator.html)